# UI libraries that are framework independent

Tags: web-development

Recently I encountered a problem at work where a huge enterprise application got stuck in Angular v6 due to the fact that the UI uses an external framework (SmartAdmin) which is no longer supported. As a result, due to the outdated dependencies, the build breaks from time to time. There is no other option than rewriting now :(

Does anyone know any UI libraries that don't rely on other frontend frameworks (e.g. React, Angular)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Syncfusion Angular Component Library

https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-components

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion